# How to reliably estimate a random sum of unreliable elements?

Tags: standard-deviation, descriptive-statistics, robust

This is an ill posed problem I'm faced with at work.

I have observations $X_i$, $i = 1,2,3,...N > M$.  I need want to compute $S = \sum_{i=1}^M X_i$.  Unfortunately, $M$ is random, and extremely noisy.   It turns out, I have some rough "goodness" measures, $w_i$ for each of the $X_i$.  That is, $w_i$ low, means I don't trust $X_i$ very much, $w_i$ high, means I trust $X_i$ a lot.

Moreover, "generally" as $i$ gets large, the $X_i$ get small.  (There's a lot of dependence between $M$ and the $X_i$)

In this application, it turns out that the *average* of the $X_i$ can very reliably (i.e. with relatively small standard deviation) be computed by: $A = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^M w_i X_i}{\sum_{i=1}^M w_i}$.  We know the standard deviation of $A$ is relatively small by running a number of independent trials, and computing the sample standard deviation.

But, I similarly need a "good" estimate (i.e. small standard deviation) of the straight sum of the $X_i$ and the obvious approach:  $M * A$ has far too much variance for our application.

Understand this is pretty vague, but any thoughts on how to proceed?

Comment: (Taking the $X$'s to be independent, speak up if this is not reasonable), if you replace $w_i$ with the precision (inverse of the variance) of $X_i$, you will get a smaller-variance estimate of $A$. Of course you probably have no idea what the precision *is*, and $w_i$ may be your best notion of something like it, in which case you may not be able to do much.

Comment: @Glen_b For the sake of this discussion, we can assume the $X$'s are independent.  However, I have no clue as to the precision, $w_i$ is my best guess.  But not seeing how you are working around the noisiness of $M$....

Comment: My apologies. I missed that M is a random variable where M and X are negatively correlated. How are you computing the variance of the numerator of $A$?

Comment: @Glen_b reworded original question to get at your confusion.  $X_i$ get small as $i$ gets large, not $M$ (bad wording on my part) and I added a discussion of how we know $A$ is "small enough" standard deviation.